# Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

ERROR:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' with an
>   index of type 'String'

CODE:

```
  func getApple(appleId: String) {
     var apples = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("apples_array")
     println(apples[appleId])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be:

```
var apples = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("apples_array")
println(apples?[appleId])
```

The issue here is that type `[NSObject : AnyObject]?` implies an optional type, which means you're attempting to call a subscript on what is essentially an enum.  When you try to do this, there's no subscript declared, so the system chokes.

By adding the `?` we're saying, unwrap this value if possible, and then call the subscript.  This way the system infers to look on type `[NSObject : AnyObject]` for subscript declarations and everything is ok.

You could also use `!` to force an unwrap, but this will crash if `apples` is nil.  Another possible way to write this would be:

```
let apples = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("apples_array") ?? [:]
println(apples[appleId])
```

This way, apples is no longer optional and it will always have the subscript syntax.  No unwrapping necessary.

Comment: Well I have this issue, but my dictionary is not optional...
Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: @SwiftMatt I'm not sure, but that change possible game with Swift 2.x. The solution is still the same.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is far more clear to use optional binding so that the println is only invoked when there is an actual value to print

```
func getApple(appleId: String) {
     if let apples = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("apples_array") {
        println(apples[appleId])
     }
}
```