# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]?' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: swift

```
   let orch = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("orch_array")?[orchId] as? [String:String]
   orch[appleId]
```

Errors on the `orch[appleId]` line with:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]?' with an index
>   of type 'String'

WHY?

Question #2:

```
   let orch = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("orch_array")?[orchId] as! [String:[String:String]]
   orch[appleId] = ["type":"fuji"]
```

Errors with: "Cannot assign the result of this expression"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot subscript a value of type '\[NSObject : AnyObject\]?' with an index of type 'String'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994541/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-nsobject-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to use the subscript on an optional value. You're casting to `[String: String]` but you're using the conditional form of the casting operator (`as?`). From the documentation:

> This form of the operator will always return an optional value, and the value will be nil if the downcast was not possible. This enables you to check for a successful downcast.

Therefore `orch` is of type `[String: String]?`. To solve this you need to:

**1.** use `as!` if you know for certain the type returned is `[String: String]`:

```
// You should check to see if a value exists for `orch_array` first.
if let dict: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("orch_array")?[orchId] {
    // Then force downcast.
    let orch = dict as! [String: String]
    orch[appleId] // No error
}
```

**2.** Use optional binding to check if `orch` is `nil`:

```
if let orch = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("orch_array")?[orchId] as? [String: String] {
    orch[appleId] // No error
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @abakersmith Thank you, and now, if I get slightly more complex, why can't I [orchId] as! [String: [String:String]  and then it won't let me orch["id"] = ["type":"fuji"]

Comment: Could you post that as an edit to your question? It's a bit hard to following without proper formatting.

Comment: That error is because you've declared `orch` as a constant (with `let`). If you use `var` instead you'll be able to edit its contents.

Comment: Is there any benefit to doing it the first way?  Seems like the second way does exactly the same thing except shorter and safer.