# Swift: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, NSObject>?'

Tags: swift, closures, alamofire

**EDIT: Not a DUPLICATE:**

That solution gives `'Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments'` error.  So, no this is NOT a duplicate.

Here is the function declaration.

```
        func auth(user: String, pass: String, completion: (returned: Bool, error: Bool, response: Dictionary<String, NSObject>?) -> ()){
```

`response` can be nil
}

Now I'm trying to access value passed back in another file and getting an error:

```
        if let labelString = response["error_description"] as! String?{
            self.labelPrompt.text = labelString
        }
```

**Error:**  Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary?' with an index of type 'String'

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot subscript a value of type '\[NSObject : AnyObject\]?' with an index of type 'String'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994541/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-nsobject-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type)

Comment: It **is** a duplicate. See Eric D's correct answer below. (voted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* a duplicate of the linked question: what you need is to unwrap the dictionary before using it with a subscript.

There's many ways ("if let", etc) and the linked answer gives the solution of using "optional binding" by adding a `?` between the variable holding the dictionary and the subscript.

Example in a Playground:

```
var response: Dictionary<String, NSObject>? = nil

// NOTICE THE "?" BETWEEN THE VARIABLE AND THE SUBSCRIPT

if let labelString = response?["error_description"] as? String {
    println(labelString)  // not executed because value for key is nil
}

response = ["test":"yep"]

if let labelString = response?["test"] as? String {
    println(labelString)  // "yep"
}
```

Another way of unwrapping the dictionary:

```
if let responseOK = response, let test = responseOK["test"] as? String {
    println(test) // "yep"
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The linked answer did not work; however, `if let responseOK = response, let test = responseOK["test"] as? String {
    println(test) // "yep"
}` did.