# Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String' in swift4

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    //print(userInfo)
    // Print APS.
    let aps = userInfo["aps"]
    let itemId = aps!["category"] as! String
    print("ITEM ID: \(itemId)")
    let temp = Int(itemId)
    if (temp > 0) {
        print("handle item details”)
    } else {
        print("open home")
    }
}
```

The line `let aps = userInfo["aps"]` gives the following error

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Start by using the proper signature for `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. Please review the UIApplicationDelegate documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot subscript a value of type '\[NSObject : AnyObject\]' with an index of type 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141190/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-nsobject-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], 
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String:Any] {

    }
 }
```

//

OR

```
func  application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {}
```

Comment: I did and get the following error : Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Need to cast userInfo itself as? [ String: [ String: String ] ]

Comment: @Satachito if so it would be **as? [String:[String:Any]]** , always we don't know the deep-most type of the value

Comment: @Sh_Khan Amira needs to cast aps!["category"] as! String, so, it must be [ String: [ String: String ] ]

Comment: @Satachito and who told you that there is no other values ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan I don't care, I only answer to make this question work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to define your variables type if you don't know what type it will get.

You need to declare `aps` by your expected type:

```
let aps : [String:Any]?
```

In this case, if you couldn’t initialize `aps` variable, Xcode will tell you how you can do your job. Not always, but most of time.